# Multi-Touch Windows C#

Tags: c#, windows, multi-touch

Anyone know if there is a simple way to interpret multi-touch gestures in a C# application built for Windows desktop? This application takes multi-touch input from a touch-screen.

The following tutorial is very clear and seems reading multi-touch input on Windows is easy to do using C++: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353242(v=vs.85).aspx

Is there a way to replicate this using C#?

Thanks

Comment: Using p/invoke and a window message hook it should be relatively simple. What UI technology? WPF? Winforms?

Comment: Well this was going to be my next question. I'm not sure yet. I am thinking WPF - however, can I build these widgets using C#?

Comment: I'm not sure what widgets you are talking about...

Comment: Buttons, Text Views, Dialogs, etc.

Comment: Its a lot easier to get into the Winforms message pump, WPF supports multi-touch out of the box without p/invoke. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx

Comment: A nice. This is getting to what I am looking for. My goal is to have a Windows OpenGL application that supports Multi-Touch. I assume I will probably be using Visual Studio so the easier it is for me to build a nice looking UI without 3rd party libraries etc etc the better.